# Chrome Extension/JavaScript - Saving data to Chrome Sync not storing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

**Brief**

I'm making an Options page for a Chrome Extension. I have multiple fields however I'm unable to store the data for retrieval later, as it keeps storing an empty array (instead of what I'm asking it to store).

**Code**

```js
//On load
$(function() {
  $("#saveBtn").click(saveAll);
});

//Function to save all data
function saveAll() {
  var settings = [];

  //Go through all inputs with [data-input-settings] attribute
  $("[data-input-settings]:not(.ignore)").each(function(e) {
    var $t = $(this);
    var n = $t.attr("data-input-settings");
    
    //Add this setting key and value to settings array
    settings[n] = getVal(n);
  });

  //Save to storage
  chrome.storage.sync.set({
    "settings": settings
  }, function() {
    console.log(settings);
    console.log("Saved");
    
    //Output to check (development environment)
    chrome.storage.sync.get("settings", function(o) {
      console.log(o.settings);
    });
  });
}

//Function to retrieve value by field name
function getVal(field){
 return $("[data-input-settings='"+field+"']").val() || false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="settings-advanced">
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-input-settings="adv-debug">Enable debug mode</label>
  <button type="submit" id="saveBtn">Save All</button></div>
</div>
```

**Expected Output to Console** (on Save All button click when checkbox is selected):

```
[adv-debug: "on"]
Saved
[adv-debug: "on"]
```

**Actual Output to Console** (on Save All button click when checkbox is selected):

```
[adv-debug: "on"]
Saved
[]
```

When calling the following function at any stage, the output to console is "`[]`" (even when called on pageload):

```js
function retrieveAll() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get("settings", function(o) {
    console.log(o.settings);
  });
}
```

**Question**

Why isn't the `settings` array being saved to the Chrome sync storage, and what changes are needed to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
settings[n] = getVal(n);
```

since `n` is a string and not a number, you are adding a property to the array `settings`, not adding values to it. Remember that arrays are objects, too. After that operation, `settings` is still a zero-length array with another property (in your case `avd-debug: "on"` ).

You can try to one of these two things:

1) declare `settings` as an object instead of an array. I.e. change

```
var settings = [];
```

for

```
var settings = {};
```

2) add key:value pairs to `settings` array using, for instance, `push`, like:

```
settings.push({[n]:getVal(n)});
```